# What's the meaning of "stand" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a verse from the song Billy Jean by Micheal Jackson ([this](http://www.lyrics.net/lyric/25501102) is the full version of the lyrics of the song):

> For forty days and forty nights
>   Law was on her side
>   But who can stand when shes in demand
>   Her schemes and plans
>   Though we danced on the floor in the round
>   So take my strong advice
>   Just remember to always think twice
>   (Do think twice, do think twice)

In line 3 of the verse *But who can stand when shes in demand*, what does "stand" mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of song lyrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lyric is saying "who can stand her schemes and plans"

So I think the appropriate definition of this is from the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stand):

4.1 [With modal and usually negative] informal - Be able to endure or tolerate:

Comment: The lyric's syntax is probably something like this, "Who can stand, when she's in demand, her schemes and plans?"

Comment: I missed out the demand part to maximise my point, but absolutely, yes.

I suppose "Who can stand her schemes and plans when she's in demand" would ensure full understanding of what our good friend Mr Jackson is saying.